# What is the fastest rendering method with Graphics2D?

Tags: java, awt, graphics2d

I'm creating a program that requires large amounts of particles to be rendered and manipulated.

So far I've considered using...

- `g2.drawLine(x, y, x, y);`
- `g2.fillOval(x-3, y-3, 6, 6);`
- `BufferedImage`
- `ImageIcon`

What is the fastest way to render a lot of particles and is an image faster than using methods such as `drawLine()` or `fillOval()`?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, all the rendering methods are pretty linear in their render times, using `drawPoly` doesn't seem any faster than using multiple `drawLine`s. As for `drawOval`, `drawRect` and `drawImage`, it simply matters how many pixels where changed. So I wouldn't worry about refactoring your rendering to use 'faster' methods when they will simply get slower the more pixels changed - you should instead try not drawing over anything/much.

All the parameters of most of the rendering methods can be tweaked at any time using the `setRenderingHint` method, you can change the interpolator used for image scaling, antialiasing quality, alpha blending... Using this well along with not drawing over pixels will give the best performance.
For example with your particles, if they do not use alpha - turn it off, If they're all aligned to 90 degree angles - turn off antialiasing, you can also set the colour rendering quality depending on your image.